# How can I get list of all MUC ROOMs in which particular user is participant or owner using openfire rest API

Tags: rest, api, xmpp, openfire

I am using openfire version 4.2.1 currently and I am not able to find api which provide me list of my MUC room in which I am member.

How can I get above result using openfire rest api ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [retrieve all user groups](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/restapi/readme.html#retrieve-all-user-groups) endpoint, specifying the username as part of the URl.

GET /users/{username}/groups

Comment: Thanks @dbh . I forgot to mention here that I am looking for MUC rooms.Sorry I was not clear in question earlier. Is there way to get MUC room list in which particular user is member ?

Comment: You probably need to get all chat rooms , and parse the members , participants, and owners, matching on the desired user name to get the list of this MUC rooms for the user.         GET http://example.org:9090/plugins/restapi/v1/chatrooms